# Fancy arrow patch not starting where I tell it to start

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created my own quiver function in python using matplotlib (The provided quiver plot doesn't satisfy some of my needs, thats not important.) My function is below and I've made it plots little green circles where the arrows are meant to start (image below). The arrows always seem to be offset by the same amount in the direction of where they are pointing. The arrow starting position and the circle position is exactly the same.

```
def my_own_quiver_function(axis, X_pos, Y_pos, X_val, Y_val):
standard_vel = 500000.
scale_factor = 0.0005
vels = np.hypot(X_val, Y_val)
vels = vels/(standard_vel)
widths = vels**2.
widths = widths.clip(max=1.0)
for xp in range(len(X_pos[0])):
    for yp in range(len(Y_pos[0])):
        xvel = X_val[xp][yp]*scale_factor
        yvel = Y_val[xp][yp]*scale_factor
        width_val = widths[xp][yp]
        axis.add_patch(mpatches.Circle((X_pos[xp][yp], Y_pos[xp][yp]), radius=0.1, lw=0.5, color='m'))
        axis.add_patch(mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((X_pos[xp][yp], Y_pos[xp][yp]), (X_pos[xp][yp]+xvel, Y_pos[xp][yp]+yvel), color='w', linewidth=1.*width_val, mutation_scale=30.*width_val,arrowstyle='->'))
```

Urgh I don't have enough reputation points but the image can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjH2P.jpg

It's really frustrating that they quiver looks all wonky because of this.

EDITS:I've tried removing the mutation because the documentation says its squeezes and stretches the arrow, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a parameter you can change. Have a look at the other parameters for `FancyArrowPatch`. There's something that move arrows away from the start and end point for the case where you don't want it to overlap with text.

Comment: Thanks! It was "shrink". The description for that variable is really not very clear at all and I think it really shouldn't be the default.

Comment: The arrow patches are designed for when you're adding annotations, and so I don't think they thought about them much outside of that context.

Comment: By the way, if you have the answer you can post it yourself to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jezzamon for pointing out the ShrinkA and ShrinkB inputs. The default for these is set to 2.0, probably meant to make sure the arrow doesn't overlap with another annotation such as text or a shape. I set these to 0.0 and it fixed it! I personally think it shouldn't defaulted to that... but there you go!